# Question migrated from SO to SU, but one answer remains active

Tags: bug, status-completed, migration, deleted-answers

I answered a question on Stack Overflow a few weeks ago:

- [Google ‘Im feeling lucky’ (Stack Overflow)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2342687/google-im-feeling-lucky)

Which got migrated to Super User:

- [Google ‘Im feeling lucky’ (Super User)](https://superuser.com/questions/113909/google-im-feeling-lucky)

However, for some reason, I have just noticed that [this answer by SLaks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2342687/google-im-feeling-lucky/2342710#2342710) remained active, even though the question is marked as closed and migrated. This answer can still receive votes and comments.

Comment: Oh thank god, someone talking about something *other* than rep recalcs.

Comment: @Ether nooooo! A question that's not about rep recalcs. This effectively breaks the streak of most questions on meta about the exact same stupid thing.

Comment: This no longer happens, some additional checks are in place.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The author of that answer chose to undelete it after the question was migrated.  Seems to be just bad manners on their part, but it only seems rarely done.  I've only seen a handful, one being the same user you noticed here [undeleting an answer today](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2489499/sudden-loss-of-reputation-points/2489501#2489501).

I can't recall if you need to be a 10k user to access the undelete link or not, and you can still only affect your own answers.

It does appear to me that you are missing votes on the migrated answer.

Comment: From memory, I've also seen this happen if the answer was in progress when the question was migrated. Perhaps we need a batch job that periodically moves these answers across to the target site if they're not already there, or just delete them if they are?

Comment: Thanks for the answer... I was not aware of this. It does seem like a bug, however. I don't think this is intentional.

Comment: I think it was done to illustrate this very point, but I can't find the question where it was mentioned.